# How to create a NSMutableURLRequest with AES 256 encryption and base 64 encoding in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have to post a `NSMutableURLRequest` with json as request body on the client server. What i'm doing is

1) Encrypting `json` with `AES 256 Encryption`.

2) `Base 64 encoding` that encrypted data.

3) Again converting the encoded string to  `NSData` and set it as "`setHTTPBody`" of the request.

Now, what i got from the server is response `status code "500"`.

I don't know what exactly is the cause of the problem. Please help me out.

PS:- While encrypting i'm giving a string as an key for encryption. Is it something(key) i need to mention on the server too ???

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you need to do, is to check in which encoding your server is receing data. It's quite strange, that you need to do Base64 encoding before sending Json string. As usual you should only send data using UTF8 encoding or another encoding supported by your server.Maybe better first to use proxy program like Fiddler to test the server. Then when you will receive correct answer with status code "200", you will know how to do it right.
Another hint. Do you setting Content-length for your data?

```
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [yourData length]];
[req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```